# Get Exceptions thrown by methods of dataprovider in parent class

Tags: java, testng

I have a TestClass which is extending CommonTest class, there is a method doSomething() inside @Dataprovider of test class which is failing. I want capture the stacktrace in @AfterClass without using try/catch in @Dataprovider

```
class CommonTest {

    @AfterClass
    captureFailures() {
    }

}

class TestClass {

    @DataProvider
    sampleMethod() {

        CommonUtils.doSomething()

    }

}

class CommonUtils {

    doSomething()

}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To capture the stacktrace of the failed method in the `@DataProvider` without using try/catch, you can use the `ITestResult` object provided by TestNG. Here's an example implementation of the `captureFailures()` method in the `CommonTest` class:

```
    @Dataprovider
    class CommonTest {
        private static List<Throwable> failures = new ArrayList<>();
    
        @AfterMethod
        public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) {
            if (result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
                failures.add(result.getThrowable());
            }
        }
    
        @AfterClass
        public void captureFailures() {
            if (!failures.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Failures captured in @DataProvider:");
                for (Throwable failure : failures) {
                    failure.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    class TestClass extends CommonTest {
        @DataProvider
        public Object[][] sampleMethod() {
            CommonUtils.doSomething();
            return new Object[][]{{}};
        }
    }
    
    class CommonUtils {
        public static void doSomething() {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to do something");
        }
    }
```

In this implementation, we use an `ArrayList` to store any `Throwable` objects that are captured by the `afterMethod()` method. This method is called after each test method, including methods annotated with `@DataProvider`. If the test result is a failure, we add the `Throwable` object to the `failures` list.

In the `captureFailures()` method, we check if the `failures` list is not empty. If there are any failures, we print out the stacktrace of each `Throwable` object in the list.

Note that we have also made the `CommonTest` class abstract and extended it in the `TestClass` class. This is because we want to use the `afterMethod()` method in the `CommonTest` class to capture the failures in the `@DataProvider` method of the `TestClass`.

Comment: thanks Sa'eedeh, but if there are failures in dataprovider method then after method won't be invoked and so the won't be able to get ITestResult

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that if there are failures in the @DataProvider method, the @AfterMethod or @AfterClass methods may not be invoked, and therefore you may not be able to get the ITestResult object.
In this case, you can use a ITestContext object to store the exception that is thrown in the @DataProvider method, and then retrieve it in the @AfterMethod or @AfterClass method. Here's an example implementation:

```
    class CommonTest {
    @AfterMethod
    captureFailures(ITestResult result) {
        Throwable throwable = result.getThrowable();
        if (throwable != null) {
            // Log or handle the exception here
        }
    }

    @AfterClass
    captureFailures(ITestContext context) {
        Throwable throwable = context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().stream()
                .map(ITestResult::getThrowable)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        if (throwable != null) {
            // Log or handle the exception here
        }
    }
}

class TestClass {
    @DataProvider
    sampleMethod() {
        try {
            CommonUtils.doSomething();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            throw new SkipException("Skipping test due to exception in data provider", t);
        }
    }
}

class CommonUtils {
    static void doSomething() {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation assumes that you are using a testing framework that supports the ITestContext and SkipException objects, such as TestNG. If you are not using such a framework, you may need to modify the implementation accordingly.

Comment: thank you Sa'eedeh, ITextContext is used in the framework but I want to capture exceptions without without throwing explicitly through dataprovider method. able to do it for methods using "context.getFailedConfigurations().getAllResults();" but not able to do it for dataprovider methods